# VBA Check if button has been clicked

Tags: vba, button, click

I think this is an easy fix, but I've been stuck at this trouble spot for hours now.

Basically in the excel worksheet I have two buttons assigned to macros: 1 and 2.  If the user clicks 1 first and then clicks then 2, 2 runs off of some of the variables from 1.  But I need 2 to be able to operate independently if 2 is clicked first.  Therefore, I need some way in the 2 code to ask if 1 button has been clicked.

Both 1 and 2 are public subs.  I think there is something that I am missing with the definitions, but I'm not sure.

Simple Sample:

```
Public Sub 1()
do this
End Sub

Public Sub 2()
If 1 clicked then
   process a
Else
   process b
End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set a Public Boolean and use that

For example

```
Dim ButtonOneClick As Boolean 'Make sure this is before all subs

Sub Button1_Click()
ButtonOneClick = True
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
If ButtonOneClick Then
    MsgBox "Button 1 Was Clicked"
Else
    MsgBox "Button 1 Was NOT Clicked"
End If

ButtonOneClick = False
End Sub
```